# Magical flight competitions

Tags: magic, flight, sports

In a civilization where a portion of the population is capable of flight, I'm trying to imagine what kind of competition would be organized.

Details as follows:

- Skills measured are speed and aerobatic prowess
- Collision detection is in place (if a flyer bumps into another flyer or a building, they are teleported out)
- Flyers can form cocoons of air around them, allowing them to safely reach supersonic speed and go under water for brief periods of time
- Flyers can provoke blasts of air (as in, they're able to) that can force other flyers to deviate from their intended course
- Flyers don't have superhuman resistance to acceleration and otherwise behave like normal human beings
- I would ideally like for flyers to interact with each other

I dismissed the idea of a straightforward obstacle race (ex. Star Wars' podrace), and added a token object flyers would have to fight each other for (inspired by the Quaffle in Harry Potter's Quidditch).

I'm having trouble balancing the need to prevent anyone from getting hurt (collision detection) and the need for this to be more than aligning a bunch of people on a starting line and having them go as fast as possible without otherwise trying to influence the outcome for their competition.

I typically don't like the fact that Star Wars resolves this by having Anakin's competitors cheat in order for the movie to create tension during the race. I would rather this be integrated as part of the official rules and have everyone playing fair, while still having something that's interesting to follow for the spectators.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're doing this for a game? (collision detection?)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an interactive sport that is focused on direct competition between the players, rather than a race which could be abstracted to one player vs the clock. I don't know of any sports that have many one-man teams (virtually all sports have two many-man teams), so you might be looking at either a team sport or some kind of new free-for-all sport.

Comment: Broad and opinion based as-is. Perhaps you could come back with a question about the details and suitable rules once you have narrowed down the scope considerably?

Comment: Two words: aerial keijo.

Comment: This looks like a [high-concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/6986): You have an idea, but need the community to develop it for you. Voting to close as _too broad_.

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, this is an interesting question but it's much more brainstorming-style than StackExchange is prepared to handle with its one-question/best-answer model. Is there something in particular you're having trouble with when designing these competitions? I've voted to put your question on hold until you get the chance to [edit] it and fit the site better.

Answer (score 2):

**[Red Bull Air Race](http://airrace.redbull.com/)**

If you're after a flying competition designed to showcase speed and agility, look no further. If you really want to encourage interaction, have sections of the course with cross overs. This can help those at the rear to maybe air-bop the leader if the crossover points are smartly placed. Kind of a like a real life blue shell from Mario Kart...

And underwater definitely adds some complexities. There is no reason that instead of flying between pylons or through hoops that a part of the course could have a shortcut where going underwater saves a few hundred meters of track to cover.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Volleyball, Basketball and Featherball you can have a game in which:

- The Players are divided in 2 teams
- The Players have net-sticks aka. featherball bats
- The Players aren't allowed to touch each other **OR** keep the ball
- The Players are allowed to touch the ball one time to pass to another teammate or shoot on the goal (playing the ball two times with the bat or holding the ball on the net is forbidden/ a foul)
- Players can block other players, by standing/ flying in the way (Copyied by Basketball rules)

It should be a user friendly game at this point
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

## In the real world, runners don't fight

Star Wars Ep I had a very silly podrace. There is no need to emulate that. In the real world, people generally don't respect those who fight. They respect those who follow the rules and win.

Races in the Ancient world did not usually involve fighting, despite what *Ben Hur* might have told you. In fact, these races were relatively simple affairs; the chariot races were just going around in a circle. People still watch that in NASCAR today. Runners just go around in a circle, too. They did in the Olympic statium in ancient Delphi, and they do it from high school track meets to the modern Olympics.

The moral of the story is, your racers won't fight each other. They will just race. A flying race will be, first person to take off from the starting point, circle around that big tree or that mountain or that far off tower, and then get back to the starting point. The flight skills needed--speed, agility, stamina--will all be tested by the race.

As for fighting, the ancient Olympics had that too. The other set of competitions was the wrestling, but the two competitions were kept separate. There was no wrestle-race. In your competition, it is most reasonable that there will be separate events, one for racing, one for fighting.

Answer (score 1):

Making a game like this is hard.  Most games created for stories are very poorly conceived.  They suffer one common issue: they start from a list of extrinsic behaviors they want to see and craft a game around them.  If that sounds like what you did in the question, then you'd be right.

Real games don't start around rules.  They start around something you want to emphasize.  Crossfit challenges emphasize a particular kind of endurance the Crossfitters are proud of.  Gymnastics competitions emphasize a particular kind of grace that gymnasts are proud of.  Hip-hop dance competitions emphasize a different kind of grace.  Baton twirling and other related tasks emphasize fluid motion captured by spinors.

Once you identify what spark you want your sport to fan, then the external goals come into play.  Soccer technically has the goal of putting the ball in the other team's goal.  But if you look at it, that's not their spark.  Their spark is found in the way these people manipulate a spherical ball at full throttle.  The goal is just there to put numbers to it.

Then you have to deal with the "cheating" rules.  100% of the time when you apply an external scoring system to capturing a spark in people, you will get it wrong.  100% of the time.  There's always a way to cheat the system to accomplish the external goal without accomplishing the internal one.  So we develop rules which prevent the cheating approach, but permit the desired behavior to be scored.  What do these rules look like?  Hand your magic system over to someone else and say "break my game."  Find out what they do.  Remember, the cheater's goal is not to demonstrate prowess.  It's to win.  They'll do it by whatever means are necessary.

The next rules are typically safety rules.  If your culture wants to emphasize playing chicken with solid objects, then rules which teleport you away become useful -- but if you teleport away that's a bust.  No score for that.  But generally popular sports are designed with safety in mind.  Even boxing and UFC matches have very strict rules about what kinds of strikes are permitted.

But all of this rules talk is second.  It does not come first.  First comes the spark you want to fan.  The thrill and excitement and prowess that makes people in your world excited.  You say "acrobatic prowess," I ask "what kind of acrobatic prowess?"  Go look at the gymnastic games.  There are *dozens* of specific acrobatic prowesses that have produced dozens of different games, each with their own rules.  There's some commonality (falling down on aerial games is bad), but each one is custom tailored to show *something*.

The really hard part is that you have to go through this process with one more thing in mind: the amateur.  There are very few successful sports which cannot be played meaningfully at the amateur level.  You have to develop a fan base that way.  There may be no amateur F-1 racing, but there are indeed amateur car racing circuits.  If you look at golf course design, they're always designed to support many skill levels.  There's always a few shots that are *just* out of reach of your skill level, no matter what your skill level may be.

But always start with the spark of inspiration that you want your sport to accentuate.

Answer (score 0):

### Air takraw

- Team game
- Players compete for control over a ball (your token) by passing constantly among team mates
- Opposing team must try to assume control
- Winner = team that maintains control within defined period (e.g. 120 minutes)
- Arena needs to be large, so that bursts of supersonic speed are viable, and varied terrain would encourage different strategies and tactics

### Aerobatics

- Rules state that players must only contact ball with specific part of body (e.g. shoulders, feet, elbows as in Thai-style takraw or perhaps hips for a real challenge as in Mesoamerican ballgames).
- Continuous passing requires well-coordinated team work at different distances
- Players are using blasts of air to divert defending players from catching passes and disrupt attacking players from positioning themselves for capture
- Could also incorporate hand bats into rules for longer passes and greater accuracy
- Alternatively, hand bat shots could be used to score extra points (or wipe off accumulated enemy seconds) in goals scattered across arena terrain, which would result in more interesting attack and defence strategies entertaining to spectators.